# Email regular expression Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, email

I have a email regex . But i want to allow only 1 to 20 characters before the `@` symbol in the regex.

```
([\w-\"]+(?:\.[\w-\"]+))@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,255})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, [learning regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-quantifier-range) might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're better off checking outside of the regex, but there happens to be a way in this specific case:

```
(?=[^@]{1,20}@)([\w-\"]+(?:\.[\w-\"]+))@...
```

Comment: +1: wrote the same expression, then saw yours. )

Comment: Done ... Stack overflow is awesome..